# TextField tooltip acting weird, doubling the text. Is there a solution other than completely changing the display logic?

Tags: tooltip, textfield, abap

[image]

The text is supposed to say simply

> 3rd. party sorting; Own sorting; Requesting supplier; Customer sort;

It contains the same value as the textfield, but it's apparently too long, so i had to set it as a Tooltip too. 
When the text is not too long for the text field, the tooltip displays correctly.

Is there a solution for this that keeps the text the way it is, but just fixes the tooltip?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot with the described behaviour? More details, e.g. this is a selection screen or one built with Screen Painter, would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need the tooltip at all.  When the field length exceeds the display length, it seems like SAP automatically puts the entire field as the tooltip.

This means that when you also set the tooltip, you get the content twice.

If you do want the tooltip, even when the fieldlength is shorter than than the length of the textfield, you can try something like this:

```
if strlen( text_field ) > 60.  "Visible length of the textfield
  clear v_tooltip.             "You have to use a separate field as the tooltip
else.
  v_tooltip = text_field.
endif.
```